# Mertens' Third Theorem for primes of the form $4n+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I am looking for upper and lower bounds for the following expression:

$$\prod_{\substack{p\le n \\ p \equiv 1\ mod\ 4}} \frac{p-1}{p}$$

Apart from the trivial one:

$$\prod_{\substack{p\le n \\ p \equiv 1\ mod\ 4}} \frac{p-1}{p} \ge \prod_{p\le n} \frac{p-1}{p}$$

Any advice or bibliographic reference will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374824/asymptotics-for-prod1-frac1p-over-all-primes-p-leq-x-with-p-equiv ?

Comment: For any $r,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(r,m)=1$ we have $\prod_{\substack{p\le x \\ p \equiv r\ mod\ m}} \frac{p-1}{p}\sim \frac{C}{\log(x)^{1/\phi(m)}}$ for some constant $C$.